# Bind failed for same driver name in /proc/crypto

Tags: cryptography, linux-device-driver, xilinx

In */proc/crypto* I have 2 drivers with same name.

```auto
name         : gcm(aes) 
driver       : xilinx-zynqmp-aes-gcm 
module    : kernel 
priority     : 200 
refcnt       : 1 
selftest     : passed 
internal     : no 
type         : aead 
async        : yes 
blocksize    : 1 
ivsize       : 12 
maxauthsize  : 16 
geniv        : <none>


name         : gcm(aes)
driver       : gcm-aes-ce
module       : kernel
priority     : 300
refcnt       : 1
selftest     : passed
internal     : no
type         : aead
async        : no
blocksize    : 1
ivsize       : 12
maxauthsize  : 16
geniv        : <none>
```

---

In a code I am trying to bind my socket to driver.

```c
struct sockaddr_alg sa = {
        .salg_family = AF_ALG,
        .salg_type = "aead",
        .salg_name = "gcm(aes)"
      };
tfmfd = socket(AF_ALG, SOCK_SEQPACKET, 0);
ret = bind(tfmfd, (struct sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof(sa));
if (ret == -1) {
    printf("bind failed %s\n", strerror(errno));
    close(tfmfd);
    return -1;
}
```

I encountered with an error.

> **bind failed No such file or directory**

Is it because if kernel finds two algorithm with same name?

Comment: I can see , kernel chooses driver as per priority if algorithm name is same .  But I am still not able to figure it out why binding is failed?

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same error.

What I determined is that the userspace calls to AEAD needed to be enabled in `petalinux-config -c kernel`

Specifically I selected:

```
<*> Userspace cryptographic algorithm configuration

<*> User-space interface for AEAD cipher algorithms
```

also you can select the xilinx version by using the `driver` instead of the `name`, if you use the name for `salg_name`

Hopefully this help others who try to follow the xilinx example, and run into issues.